# Dynamic ng-model in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects [image]

and i have a dropdown box with these names in with a text box to show the value that is inside the object that is selected
[image]

I have the input box set to

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="o.boxes.box1[0]">
```

is there a way to set "box1[0]" to the selected dropdown value? the dropdown box is selectedNumber. I tried ng-model="o.boxes.{{selectedNumber}}[0]" but this didnt work.

ng-model="o.boxes.{{selectedNumber}}[0]"

Comment: I think you are forced to split the logic in two parts: 1) have to dropdown to be an array of either objects, either strings and bind the ng-model to it of the selected key (box1, box2, ecc) as a string. 2) Bind, to the input, the selected element, like: `ng-model="o.boxes[selectedBox][0]"`. The approach of referencing an array value to an input is, however, quite strange, you usually bind object properties to views, rather than array elements. If I were you, I would start by chaning the leading model.

Comment: ng-model="o.boxes[selectedNumber][0]" worked but the textbox copys on every row even though i use the o object from ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with just a lit refactor of your code.
The best way to do this should be: update input **ng-model** reference with the current selection of your dropdown.

In your Controller:

```
$scope.boxes = {
    box1: [],
    box2: [],
    box3: []
}
$scope.selectedBoxModel = null;

$scope.onDropdownSelection = function (selectedBox) {
    $scope.selectedBoxModel = selectedBox;
}
```

And in your template on your input you will reference the **ng-model** with the selected box:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedBoxModel[0]">`

Answer (score 0):

> Try giving run time expression evaluation as shown below.

```
 ng-model="o.boxes[{{selectedNumber}}][0]"
```